# How to prevent XML parsing errors being written to System.err (stderr)?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am writing some unit tests that are deliberately passing bad strings to the Java DOM XML parser.

E.g.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

String message_xml = ""; // Empty string, not valid XML!!!
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(message_xml.getBytes());
Document doc = db.parse(input);
```

This is correctly throwing a SAXParseException (which is what my unit test expects).  But it is also writing a message to System.err (stderr) in the Java console:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
```

Is there any way to configure the XML parser to NOT write to stderr?

I'm using Java 1.6SE.

Comment: Try configuring the package's loggers? But why does it matter--they're unit tests.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Install your own [`ErrorHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html):

```
db.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }
});
```